# Fullcalendar add icon to event and not trigger eventClick

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, fullcalendar

I'm trying to add custom "options" icon to the event. I want that if i click on this icon, small tooltip appears. But if i click on this icon, eventClick is triggered.

**This is my html**

```
<div class="fc-event-content">
   <div class="fc-event-title" style="float: left">
     <div class="title_info" id="prvni_radek">Text on row one</div>
     <div class="title_info">Text on row two</div>
   </div>
   <div class="tecky"><img src="./image/tecky.png"></div>
</div>
```

**I tried this JS**

```
<script>
$(".tecky").on("click", function(event){
  event.stopPropagation();
  alert("test");
});
</script>
```

event.stopPropagation(); i found in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12002468/fullcalendar-unbind-the-eventclick-method-for-the-clickable-icons-placed-on-the) article but it won't help

Comment: When do you run the script? Is fullcalendar rendered when you run it?

Answer (score 1):

Try use event.preventDefault(). It should help you.

Answer (score 0):

if event.stopPropagation() does not work, give the below a try

```
$( '#outer' ).click ( function ( event ) {
      if ( $( event.target ).is( '#inner' ) ) {
            //code if inner got clicked
      } else {
            //code if outer got clicked
      }
}
```